# How to change sign up confirmation link in devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, subdomain

I want to change sign up confirmation link in devise.

At the sign up time actually I got this type of link "http://localhost:3000/companies/confirmation?confirmation_token=KjN-vnApU1GBYfso2LTA"

but instead of this i want the link some what like this "http://subdomain.lvh.me:3000/companies/confirmation?confirmation_token=KjN-vnApU1GBYfso2LTA"

in short I want to pass subdomain with link. so how can i do that?

Please help me out.

I am new in rails.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pass subdomain with confirmation link to get the sign in link with subdomain like below :

```
link_to 'Click here to finish setting up your account on RightBonus',
confirmation_url(@resource, :confirmation_token => @resource.confirmation_token, :subdomain => @resource.subdomain)
```

Answer (score 1):

In development.rb find the following and change it to

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'lvh.me:3000' }
```

Answer (score 0):

@jiggs and @RSB

thanks for reply.

I used both of your answers and I get it perfectly works.

and also found another solution is that change in after_confirmation_path_for method of confirmation controller. just redirect to sign_in method with subdomain. like below:

```
def after_confirmation_path_for(resource_name, resource)
 'http://' + resource.domain_name + '.lvh.me:3000/signin'
end
```